# events concept in yii2

Tags: events, yii2

I have gone throught the guide from :
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-events.html

but I have simple confusion here is that:

// this handler is a static class method
$foo->on(Foo::EVENT_HELLO, ['app\components\Bar', 'methodName']);

the above event will be fired on the execution of method : 'methodName' of class 'app\components\Bar' ?

OR

method : 'methodName' of class 'app\components\Bar' will be fired on the call of above event ?

Answer (score 0):

method : 'methodName' of class 'app\components\Bar' will be fired on the call of above event.

To fire event on execution of method you must triggering event - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-events.html#triggering-events